# How to trigger a notification if label is dropped on wrong target?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sklabelnode

In this drag and drop game ([adapted from this tutorial](http://tutorials.tinyappco.com/SwiftGames/DragDrop)), the player has to match the label to the right target. I have it set so that if the touch ends and the label's center is inside the target, it is removed from the screen and the game starts over.

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

  if label.name == "letters" {
    if lettersBin.frame.contains(label.position) {
        // remove it and create a new label
        label.removeFromParent()
        setupDragLabel()
```

However, I want to trigger a notification if the player drops the wrong label onto the bin, so:

```
else if label.name == "numbers" {
 if lettersBin.contains(label.position) ...
```

What would I write to finish this? Do I make another label appear on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easiest to use a UIAlertController.  You can add the messages along with button actions to display that the user was wrong.

```
let converterAction = UIAlertController(title: "Your title here", message: "Your message to the user here", preferredStyle: .alert)
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default){ _ in
    //Any custom action to happen here
}
converterAction.addAction(okAction)

present(converterAction, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I can't use UIAlertController within the GameScene: `self.present(alert, animated: true)` creates an error.

Comment: Can you post your code or say what class your GameScene inherits from?

Comment: This was the follow-up question/answer I ended up working with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51884294/attempt-to-present-uialertcontroller-on-uiviewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-i?noredirect=1#comment90723789_51884294

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to show an alert, you can do the following:

1. Add a label to the Storyboard and to your file.
2. Set that label to be hidden by default.
3. Programatically set `label.isHidden = false` and set it's text as you wish.

What I now labeled "label" can be anything though, you could even create a group of views and hide/show them all at once. Useful when wanting to show a Progress Indicator and a "Loading..." Label at the same time.